# How to add date not null validation in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

This video shows how to add validation for a textbox:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb643821.aspx

What about date ? I can't make it work for date.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that I would suggest is to use a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx).  This will take about 0 effort on your part and it will ensure that your users type the date in a certain format.  You can then attempt to parse the date into a DatTime and, if that fails, display a clue to the user as to why.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a regex validator or a custom validator (and add a supplementary Javascript/code-behind method) to validate the format of a user's input.

More info can be found here:

- [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx)
- [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx)